# React Native multiple style notation object spread vs array

Tags: react-native, styles

Is there performance or other difference in using either object spread operator or array notation for multiple style objects in React Native? Or is really doesn't matter at all?

Answer (score 0):

There could be a tiny performance difference since spread operator creates a new object, but difference would be so small it's not worth measuring. It would come down to your personal style and how your testing framework interacts with it. E.g, doing a component snapshot would show them as arrays or single objects.

The only thing to keep in mind is that the spread operator overwrites items based on order, just in the same way array ordering overwrites.